# Excel Conditional Formatting Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to make a column do this: so lets say
If the score of 4 is made from a 2 x 2 then it is green.
If the score of 4 is made from a 4 x 1 or a 1 x 4 then it is yellow.

I am done the formula for the green and the yellow but it only happens once. So if I change a 2 x 2 to 4 x 1. It will stay green. Not change to yellow.

Formula for Green (2x2):
=IF(G31=4,IF(D15=2,IF(F15=2,0,1),1),0)

Formula for Yellow (4x1, 1x4):
=IF(G31=4,IF(D15=4,IF(F15=1,0,1),1),0)

Please help me work this one out. Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV9os.jpg)

Tried the formula but does not work, even if I remove every other formula:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBnQW.png)

Comment: Does the cell you are trying to change contain `=4*1` or like `=D15*F15` ?

Comment: Hello, it contains D15*F15,thank you

Comment: I tried creating two formulas for the yellow. =IF(G31=4,IF(D15=4,IF(F15=1,0,1),1),0) and another =IF(G31=4,IF(D15=1,IF(F15=4,0,1),1),0) but didn't work

Comment: Right, so you need this to affect an entire range of cells, not just G31?

Comment: Yep that's right, thank you

Comment: Your example is misleading as you are trying to change row 31 depending upon row 15, edited my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `AND` and `OR`

Formula for Yellow (4x1, 1x4) `=AND($G31=4, OR($D15=1, $D15=4))`

Formula for Green (2x2) `=AND($G31=4, $D15=2)`

**EDIT**

As per your screenshot, if you are trying to change a range, not just cell `G31`, use the following:

Formula for Yellow (4x1, 1x4) `=AND($G1=4, OR($D1=1, $D1=4))`

Formula for Green (2x2) `=AND($G1=4, $D1=2)`

Change the number `1` for the starting row of your cells (3, 4, 5 whatever) and set the Range to be `=$G$1:$G$100` again changing the `1` and `100` for your start and end row.

I cannot stress enough, if your data does not start in row 1, you will need to edit the above to suit your needs.

Comment: =IF(G31=4,IF(D15=4,IF(F15=1,0,1),1),0)=AND($G31=4, OR($D15=1, $D15=4))

Comment: But the colour does not change

Comment: It changes the Green, but if I change the number from 2 x 2 to 4 x 1, it will stay the same colour

Comment: D and F needs to be 2 for Green                                                                D and F needs to be either 4 x 1 or 1 x 4 to be yellow

Comment: Yes, but you can ignore F in this outcome, if G=4 and D=2, F can only  =2, no need to use your `IF`, just create two condition formatting rules, one that says `=AND($G31=4, OR($D15=1, $D15=4))` for yellow, and the other that says `=AND($G13=4, $D15=2)` for Green.

Comment: Likewise if G=4 and D = either 1 or 4, your conditions are met.

Comment: Edited to add screen shots.

Comment: Sorry it does not work, now it is changing the colour of 6 and 3s to yellow instead of 4

Comment: Have you removed your other conditional formatting rules? You must have some more rules affecting the cell as the above will not do anything if you have 6 or 3's and `G31` would never equal 4 if you have 6 and 3's (without using fractions)

Comment: Yup I removed, Please see image link on my question, thank you

Comment: Your second image isn't the same as I have written. You have applied it to the range `$G$93:$G$103`, as per my answer, the range needs to be `=$G$1:$G$100`.